# Python: calculation of italian fiscal code

Tags: python

I have a DataFrame where I have all the info to calculate the Italian Fiscal Code for individuals but I am facing the following problem.
I am trying to use the function below to calculate the Fiscal Code but in case of error (for example it is not able to calculate the fiscal code because of a country doesn't exist anymore), the function always write, for each line, what is in the except instead of writing the fiscal code where all the info are available and correct and what is in the except only in case a error is find.
Could you help me to find a solution?
Thanks

def check(df_PF):

```
    try:
        a=[codicefiscale.encode(surname=df_PF['cognome'][i], 
                                name=df_PF['nome'][i], 
                                birthdate=(df_PF['data_nascita'][i]), 
                                sex=df_PF['tipo_sesso'][i], 
                                birthplace=df_PF['den_comune_nascita'][i]) 
               if (pd.notna(df_PF['cognome'][i])) & 
                  (pd.notna(df_PF['nome'][i])) & 
                  (pd.notna(df_PF['data_nascita'][i])) & 
                  (pd.notna(df_PF['tipo_sesso'][i])) & 
                  (pd.notna(df_PF['den_comune_nascita'][i])) 
               else None for i in range(0,len(df_PF))]
        return(a)
    except: 
            pass
            return ('Not Available')
```

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki its an inline if statement in the list comprehension so no `:` needed

Comment: Ok, then the problems are reduced to: 1) Use of bitwise operator `&` instead of logical operator `and` 2) Don't use a bare except, capture an specific exception.

Comment: Hello Andreas and welcome! Make sure your title is a question. "Python: calculation of italian fiscal code" is not a good title, people with similar issues won't be able to find your question.